# How to convert files with Spark, while keeping folders structure

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have bunch of csv files ordered in folders, in Hive partitioning pattern (`s3://csvfiles/Y=2017/M=10/D=12/H=23/M=12/...`).

So, I have few files on each "hour" folder, in csv format.
I want to combine all files of specific hour, into a single file in ORC format, write it into a different root folder, but keeping the "dates" patterns.
so the result will be something like that:

```
s3://orcfilesY=2017/M=10/D=12/H=23/singlefile.orc
```

Is it possible to do it with Spark?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`repartition` and `partitionBy`:

```
val n: Int

df
  .partitionBy(n, $"Y", $"M", $"D", $"H")
  .write.partitionBy("Y", "M", "D", "H").orc(...)
```

Comment: AFAIK this will ignore the partitioning I already have in the source folders - it will read all the data and will repartition it.
I found that for parquet files, if I will define "basepath" it will do "partition discovery" (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery).

How to do that

Comment: AFAIK this will ignore the partitioning I already have in the source folders - it will read all the data and will repartition it.
I found that for parquet files, if I will define "basepath" it will do "partition discovery" [https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery].

Is it doable also for csv files?
As in my source the data have partitioned also by minutes, and on the destination I want it to be partition only by Y/M/D/H.
If I will repartition by part of the keys, is it will reshuffle all the data?